# Wildcard character use in TeXWorks find

Tags: texworks

Is it possible to use wildcard characters in `TeXworks` when you search for something? I can see that there is a "Regular expression" option, but I was thinking along the lines of something more user friendly.

My Example where for instance `*` would be the wildcard character: Searching for something like `\setcounter{subsection}{*L1}` would ideally return all of the following from my code using such functions.

- `\setcounter{subsection}{3}\subsection{}\writeVerseParams{40001004}{ypos}{F}{L1}`
- `\setcounter{subsection}{4}\subsection{}\writeVerseParams{40001005}{ypos}{F}{L1}`
- `\setcounter{subsection}{5}\subsection{}\writeVerseParams{40001006}{ypos}{F}{L1}`
- etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [TeXworks manual](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/downloads/list?can=2&q=Type%3DDocs)

> `.` **(dot)** This matches any character (including newline). So if you want
>   to match the dot, you have to escape it `\.`.

But probably you want to match anything except a newline, so `[^\n]` is what you're looking for:

```
\\setcounter\{subsection\}\{[^\n]*L1\}
```

Comment: Good stuff. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is essentially NO.

Some good regular expression explanations can be found [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html).
However for some reason it doesn't work properly on my TeXworks on my Mac...hmmmmmmmmm...

From what I can tell, my example should be able to work with a RegExp such as: `\\setcounter\{subsection\}\{.*L1\}` but doesn't.

### EDIT:

See the accepted answer for solution to this `regexp` as well.